# MySQL ALTER TABLE not actually altering the table

Tags: mysql

I'm running an ALTER TABLE command to change the character set and collation of a table, but it doesn't look like it's working.  The command runs without an error, but the table never actually updates:

```js
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE users;
--------------------------------------------------------------+
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_deprecated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`),
  KEY `id_deprecated` (`id_deprecated`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=824 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)


mysql> ALTER TABLE users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE users;
--------------------------------------------------------------+
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_deprecated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`),
  KEY `id_deprecated` (`id_deprecated`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=824 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE <table> CONVERT TO ...` converts the values stored in the table, but not the table definition itself.

`ALTER TABLE <table> CHANGE <column> ...` changes the table definition.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the update Cobra_Fast.  I did run the following on all the columns in the actual table, like:  ``ALTER TABLE users CHANGE xxxx xxxx VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci``... and all columns are now CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci... however, on a show create table, it still shows ``ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=824 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci``

Comment: What ended up working is:  ``ALTER TABLE users CHARACTER SET utf8rmb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci``.  Note there is not CONVERT or CHANGE.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working is: `ALTER TABLE users CHARACTER SET utf8rmb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Note there is not CONVERT or CHANGE.

Comment: Pfft... sorry I showed up right after you figured it out yourself. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE users 
  CHARACTER SET utf8,
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This should change the table *definition* rather than the data that's already in the table.